# Using the [Take New] restart in SBCL

Tags: error-handling, package, common-lisp

When I try to re-define a package in SBCL in such a way that causes name conflicts, I get a `NAME-CONFLICT` error with the restarts

```
 0: [KEEP-OLD] Keep symbols already accessible FOO (shadowing others).
 1: [TAKE-NEW] Make newly exposed symbols accessible in FOO, uninterning old ones.
 2: [RESOLVE-CONFLICT] Resolve conflict.
 3: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 4: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 5: [ABORT] Abort thread (#<THREAD "new-repl-thread" RUNNING {10060E47B3}>)
```

I'd like to write something that would automatically invoke the `TAKE-NEW` restart, so that I could do something like

```
(force (defpackage :foo (:use :cl :bar :baz :mumble)))
```

The result of this should be the same as calling `defpackage`, followed by manually invoking the `TAKE-NEW` restart. The problem is,

```
CL-USER> (handler-case 
         (defpackage :foo (:use :cl :bar :baz :mumble))
       (error (e) (compute-restarts e)))
(#<RESTART SWANK::RETRY {1006DC40F3}> #<RESTART ABORT {10068007E3}>
 #<RESTART ABORT {10060C7F93}>)
CL-USER>
```

I don't seem to have access to that particular restart. As confirmed when I try to invoke it:

```
CL-USER> (handler-case 
         (defpackage :foo (:use :cl :bar :baz :mumble))
       (name-conflict (e) (invoke-restart 'take-new)))

No restart TAKE-NEW is active.
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-CONTROL-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] Abort thread (#<THREAD "new-repl-thread" RUNNING {10060E47B3}>)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handler-case` exits the scope of the restarts before it transfers control to a handler; you need `handler-bind`. The two other differences between the constructs are that `handler-bind` has a different syntax (demonstrated below), and `handler-bind` doesn't transfer control -- that is, for a `handler-bind` handler to return a value it needs to explicitly transfer control, e.g. with `return-from` or `invoke-restart`.

Something like the following should work:

```
(handler-bind ((sb-ext:name-conflict
                (lambda (c)
                  (when (find-restart 'sb-impl::take-new c)
                    (invoke-restart 'sb-impl::take-new)))))
  (defpackage :foo (:use :mumble)))
```

Comment: This works. Dammit, I need to read more about condition handling in CL. Cursory search gets me [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Common_Lisp/Advanced_topics/Condition_System), [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node219.html) and (of course) [this](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html).

Comment: @Inaimathi the section "Handling in the Context of the Signaler" of this Kent Pitman [paper](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Condition-Handling-2001.html) seems to be a nice elaboration of the point at issue here. Glancing at the CLTL2 link, much of its condition discussion seems to be in chapter 29 (also by Pitman).